# Solspace calendar display event details

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

I'm trying to display a list of my solspace calendar events, with all the event fields that I have. This is my code:

```
{exp:calendar:events orderby="event_start_date" sort="asc" date_range_start="today" show_months="12" dynamic="off"}
    <p>{event_location}</p>
    <p>{event_summary}</p>
{/exp:calendar:events}
```

I don't know whether I'm doing something really silly but my event location and summary won't show. There's definitely content in these fields and the solspace examples says you can add these fields in the the exp:calendar:events tag so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I believe you need to include calendar_id="x" parameter inside {exp:calendar:events}

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why but I had the whole thing wrapped in {exp:calendar:calendars} tags? I've removed them and now it works fine.